# (Why) should I disable libvirt networks?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, libvirt, virsh

After shutting down a virtual-machine using QEMU/KVM with libvirt the libvirt default network is still active e.g.

```
$ virsh net-list --all
         Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
    --------------------------------------------
         default   active   no          yes
```

and I know that I can disable said network with virsh `net-destroy` but I am wondering whether I should and if so why, is there any performance hit?